# scale image in UIButton accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton`, and I've added an image using the method `setImage:`
The image is smaller than the bounds of the button, and so it is centered as expected.

Now, if I resize the button I want the image to shrink too. (Currently if I resize the button, my image stays the same size since my resized button is still larger in bounds than the image).

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could try button.imageEdgeInsets ...

Answer (score 1):

Just set the ContentMode of the ImageView that is inside the UIButton.

```
[[self.button imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:stretchImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `UIButton` doesn't have an `imageView` property/method.

Comment: Check the UIButton.h. It has it. @property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UIImageView *imageView  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried it. The button's image doesn't change. Remember, when I shrink my button, the button is still bigger than the the original image size. I think this solution only works when the final button size is smaller than the original image size.

Comment: @reecon: I stand corrected. Didn't know that was available.